# sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice form: can't uncheck

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a bug with an app in Symfony 1.4, in a page with a simple form :

```
$this->widgetSchema['list'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'Object', 'expanded' => true));
```

This code show a list of checkbox.
The datas are successfully loaded from the db.
On the form, I am able to check every option and validate my form.
**But impossible to uncheck an option that is already "checked"**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input name="sf_guard_user_profile[list][]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="sf_guard_user_profile_list_1" />
    <label for="sf_guard_user_profile_list_1">Option 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="checked">
      <input name="sf_guard_user_profile[list][]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="sf_guard_user_profile_list_2" checked="checked" />
      <label for="sf_guard_user_profile_list_2">Option 2</label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Does anybody have an idea ?**

Comment: This does not look symfony/doctrine relevant, but more a html or javascript bug. Can you post all the JS on the page ? Also, is it normal your first checkbox id does not match the second ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
It was a conflict with some jQueryUI plugin. I just had to disable it.

Thx for help anyway.